# Non-Planar faces issue

Tags: modeling, faces

So I have these non-planar faces forming in my mesh I don't understand why...

[image: Non-Planar Faces]

Here is the wirframe:
[image: Wireframe]

Things I have tried:

1. Selected all faces and scaled along x-axis to 0 in order to flatten the plane.
2. Tried to select the rings and (using vertex snap) snap them to the different vertices on the outside.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, to clarify, you aren't surprised you have Ngons, but about the lighting artifacts?

What are yo utying to achieve? is this to have good topology? or just look good enough unde subd?

Comment: Show some wireframe or upload blend to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The issue is not n-gons but having non-planar faces. (even quads will show artifacts if the faces are non planar).  Please edit your question and show an image of the mesh in wireframe.

Comment: So I just added the blend file and the wireframe screenshot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of "non planar faces", they are planar, this is because of smoothed normals, which are interpolating with the holes, this can be fixed with a small inset, or an edge split modifier, or reducing the auto smooth angle or marking the hole edges sharp, you can check this is the case if you set the models shading to flat.

I would recommend the marking the edges sharp method.

I don't want to meddle too much but if you were to model for a subdivisions approach this would be a lot less messy, and probably easier.

A huge amount of N-gons will limit you, if you do know very well what you need go ahead; N-gons are a tool, very much like animation interpolation that should be left only to perform menial tasks.

Comment: Originally I tried extruding the mesh but that would make everything messy, but the inset method worked!